# I can't unlock bitlocker on my drive without restarting

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I turned on bitlockeron my drive E: 
when incrypting was 15% my laptop shot down and now I can't unlock my drive.when I want to unlock, blue crean apear and system restart....

Answer (score 1):

That sucks.
Everything isn't lost beyond hope.

Have you tried Microsoft's BitLocker Repair yet ?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523219%28WS.10%29.aspx

Do you also have a method and comfort level for imaging the thumbdrive raw in case your repair efforts damage the volume and you'll have a reliable backup to revert to ?